# R plotting code behaves differently for CSVs containing different data formatted the same way

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have two CSVs for experimental data measuring the effects of a two values of a single variable. Basically the code is the same except for the name of the data frame reference is changed and the chart title. However, when I plot for one of the values two of the lines are not plotted.

**CSVs:**

oneacFFAAVSE

```
Hours,Lv1neg Mean,Lv1neg SE,HSA1 Mean,WBC11 Mean,Osg15 Mean,Osg15 SE
0,0.0769,0.0303,1.3379,1.3379,0.0769,0.0303
24,0.4750,0.0184,0.3828,0.3828,0.4750,0.0184
48,1.4191,0.1143,0.8532,0.8532,1.4191,0.1143
72,1.8043,0.3336,1.0403,1.0403,1.8043,0.3336
96,2.5937,0.1514,0.9778,0.9778,2.5937,0.1514
```

fiveacFFAAVSE

```
Hours,Lv1neg Mean,Lv1neg SE,HSA1 Mean,WBC11 Mean,Osg15 Mean,Osg15 SE
0,1.4493,0.0802,1.5176,1.6137,1.1546,0.0403
24,1.3171,0.4477,2.0841,1.0504,1.5220,0.0432
48,1.7594,0.6752,2.9946,4.7201,1.8355,0.2189
72,2.0609,0.3237,3.9435,2.3607,4.2889,0.2486
96,2.5430,0.0592,4.8377,3.8553,3.5296,0.1574
```

**R Code**

For oneac:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(oneacFFAAVSE, aes(x=Hours, y1=Lv1neg.Mean, y2=HSA1.Mean, y3=WBC11.Mean, y4=Osg15.Mean, group = 1)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lv1neg.Mean-Lv1neg.SE, ymax=Lv1neg.Mean+Lv1neg.SE), colour="#000099", width=.1) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Osg15.Mean-Osg15.SE, ymax=Osg15.Mean+Osg15.SE), colour="#FFA500", width=.1) +
    geom_line(data = oneacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, Lv1neg.Mean), colour="#000099") +
    geom_line(data = oneacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, HSA1.Mean), colour="#990050") +
    geom_line(data = oneacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, WBC11.Mean), colour="#009900") +
    geom_line(data = oneacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, Osg15.Mean), colour="#FFA500") +
    labs(title = "Nitrogen Depleted Media with 1g L-1 acetate" ,
         x = "Time (Hours)" ,
         y = "FFA (µM)")
```

For fiveac

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(fiveacFFAAVSE, aes(x=Hours, y1=Lv1neg.Mean, y2=HSA1.Mean, y3=WBC11.Mean, y4=Osg15.Mean, group = 1)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lv1neg.Mean-Lv1neg.SE, ymax=Lv1neg.Mean+Lv1neg.SE), colour="#000099", width=.1) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Osg15.Mean-Osg15.SE, ymax=Osg15.Mean+Osg15.SE), colour="#FFA500", width=.1) +
    geom_line(data = fiveacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, Lv1neg.Mean), colour="#000099") +
    geom_line(data = fiveacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, HSA1.Mean), colour="#990050") +
    geom_line(data = fiveacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, WBC11.Mean), colour="#009900") +
    geom_line(data = fiveacFFAAVSE, aes(Hours, Osg15.Mean), colour="#FFA500") +
    labs(title = "Nitrogen Depleted Media with 5g L-1 acetate" ,
         x = "Time (Hours)" ,
         y = "FFA (µM)")
```

Please don't judge the data it's a new assay and I'm ironing out the creases. More duplicates are on the way too!

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that some of the series in `oneacFFAAVSE` have the same values.  `HSA1.Mean` and  `WBC11.Mean` are the same as are `Lv1neg.Mean` and `Osg15.Mean`.  All the lines are plotting, just some are over plotting the others.

Comment: In addition, you don't need to pass the data argument to each `geom_*`, as long as it is the same passed to `ggplot`. The same with the arguments passed to `aes`.

Comment: Error in my spreadsheet! Well spotted! Thanks Dave.

Not sure how you mean, Joesp. Can you show me?